# How do I multiply an specific row in a matrix by a certain value?

Tags: r

I'm brand new to R so this is going to be a really simple question, but how would I multiply, for example, the entire second row in this matrix by x:

```
1    1    1    1    1   
2    2    2    2    2   
3    3    3    3    3   
4    4    4    4    4
```

Where each value would be 2*x in the second row.

Comment: What is `x`? Just a single value?

Answer (score 2):

Given matrix `M`, you can use the following code:

- **solution 1:** subset row 2 and multiple it by `x`

```
M[2,] <- M[2,]*x
```

- **solution 2:** apply matrix multiplication (linear matrix algebra property with diagonal matrix)

```
M <- diag(c(1,x,1,1) %*% M
```